# From Liénard-Wiechert to Feynman potential expression

Tags: electromagnetism, potential, lienard-wiechert

When studying the potential of an uniformly moving charge in vacuum, Feynman proposes to apply a Lorentz transformation on the Coulomb potential, which reads in the rest frame

$ \phi'(\mathbf r',t') = \frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac{1}{r'} $,

where $ |\mathbf r'| = r' $.
In a frame with constant velocity $ \mathbf v $ along the x-axis, he obtains the following expression:
$$ \phi(\mathbf r, t) = \frac{\gamma q}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{(\gamma(x-vt))^2+y^2+z^2}} \tag 1 $$

by transforming $ \phi = \gamma\left(\phi'+\dfrac{A'_xv}{c^2}\right) $, where $ \gamma = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}} $ and the vector potential $ \mathbf A' $ vanishes within the rest frame. Another Lorentz transformation of the time and space coordinates $ (\mathbf r', t') \rightarrow (\mathbf r,t) $ yields (1).
I suspect that (1) describes the potential at a given point for the *instantaneous* time t.
What I am wondering is how this formula is connected to the expression of Liénard and Wiechert, namely
$$ \phi(\mathbf r, t)=\dfrac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\dfrac{1}{|\mathbf r - \mathbf x(t_{ret})| - \frac{1}{c}\mathbf v(t_{ret})\cdot(\mathbf r - \mathbf x(t_{ret}))} \tag 2, $$

where $ \mathbf x(t_{ret}) $ describes the position of the charge and $ \mathbf v(t_{ret}) = \frac{d}{dt}\mathbf x(t)\bigg|_{t=t_{ret}} $ its velocity at the retarded time $ t_{ret}(\mathbf r,t) = t-\frac{|\mathbf r - \mathbf x(t_{ret})|}{c} $, respectively.

In the case of uniform motion, we have $ \mathbf x(t) = (vt,0,0)^\intercal $.

**How do I get now from (2) to (1)?**

My idea is to actually calculate an explicit expression for the retarded time and plug it into (2), which should yield (1) if I understand it correctly. By asserting that $ c^2(t-t_{ret})^2 = (x-vt_{ret})^2+y^2+z^2 $, $ t_{ret} $ can be found in terms of solving the quadratic equation, leading to the solutions

$ t_{ret}^\pm = \gamma\left(\gamma(t-\frac{vx}{c^2})\pm\sqrt{\gamma^2(t-\frac{vx}{c^2})^2-t^2+\frac{r^2}{c^2}}\right) = \gamma\left(\gamma t'\pm\sqrt{\gamma^2t'^2-\tau^2}\right)$ where $ t' $ is the Lorentz transformation of $ t $ and $ \tau = \frac{t}{\gamma} $ looks like some proper time. Plugging this into (2) looks nothing like (1), what am I missing?

Comment: You can see Feynman's derivation here: http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_21.html

Comment: Possible Duplicate  : [Deriving Heaviside-Feynman formula for the electric field of an arbitrarily moving charge from Lienard-Wiechert potential](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/139238/deriving-heaviside-feynman-formula-for-the-electric-field-of-an-arbitrarily-movi/373441#373441)

Comment: "Electromagnetism & Matter" - The Feynman Lectures on Physics,  Vol. 2  : In Sections [21-5,21-6](https://imgur.com/a/9mCgh) Feynman derives the Liénard and Wiechert potentials and answers exactly what are you asking for in the latter section. I think that you must not expect a better answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at Feynman Volume II Section 21-6, he walks through this calculation.  Your idea and initial assertion look good; the trick is to manage the algebra to get to the final form you want.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Let the following symbols for a general curvilinear motion of the charge $\:q$ , see Figure-01.
\begin{align}
 \mathbf{r} & \equiv [\text{position 3-vector of field point}\: \mathrm A] =\left(x,y,z\right)
\tag{01a}\\
 \mathbf{x}\left(t\right) & \equiv [\text{equation of motion of charge}\: q]
\tag{01b}\\
\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\left(t\right) & \equiv [\text{velocity vector of charge}\: q]=\dfrac{\mathrm d\mathbf{x}}{\mathrm d t}
\tag{01c}\\
 \mathbf{x}^{\boldsymbol{*}} & \equiv [\text{retarded position of charge}\: q]=\mathbf{x}\left(t^{\boldsymbol{*}}\right)
\tag{01d}\\
 t^{\boldsymbol{*}} & \equiv [\text{retarded time of charge}\:q] =t-\dfrac{\left\Vert\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{x}^{\boldsymbol{*}}\right\Vert}{c}
\tag{01e}\\
\boldsymbol{\upsilon}^{\boldsymbol{*}} & \equiv [\text{velocity vector at retarded time }\: t^{\boldsymbol{*}}]=\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\left(t^{\boldsymbol{*}}\right)
\tag{01f}
\end{align}
For given equation of motion $\:\mathbf{x}\left(t\right)\:$ the retarded quantities, position and time, are functions of the field point position vector $\:\mathbf{r}\:$ and present time $\:t$ :
\begin{align}
 \mathbf{x}^{\boldsymbol{*}} & =  \mathbf{x}^{\boldsymbol{*}}\!\left(\mathbf{r},t\right)
\tag{02a}\\
t^{\boldsymbol{*}}& = \, t^{\boldsymbol{*}}\!\left(\mathbf{r},t\right)
\tag{02b}
\end{align}
Always we have such a pair of retarded quantities if the charge $\:q\:$ exists far in the past from the present time $\:t$. Moreover this pair is unique (these conclusions fall under the derivation of the Lienard-Wiechert potentials).

With these symbols the Lienard-Wiechert scalar potential at field point $\:\mathrm A\:$ is
\begin{equation}
\phi(\mathbf r, t)=\dfrac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\dfrac{1}{\left\Vert\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{x}^{\boldsymbol{*}}\right\Vert - \dfrac{\:\boldsymbol{\upsilon}^{\boldsymbol{*}}}{c}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\left(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{x}^{\boldsymbol{*}}\right)}
\tag{03}
\end{equation}
What we have to do is to prove that this equation in case of a charge moving with constant velocity $\:\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\left(t\right)=\boldsymbol{\upsilon}=\textbf{constant}\:$ is the Lorentz equation 
\begin{equation}
\phi(\mathbf{r},t) = \dfrac{\gamma q}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\bigl[\gamma\left(x-\upsilon t\right)\bigr]^2+y^2+z^2}}
\tag{04}
\end{equation}
This will be accomplished if we eliminate the retarded quantities from (03) expressing them as functions of the present quantities. More precisely, we must find the vector $\:\left(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{x}^{\boldsymbol{*}}\right)\:$ and its norm $\:\left\Vert\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{x}^{\boldsymbol{*}}\right\Vert\:$ and replace them in the denominator of the rhs of (03).

So, from the triangle $\:\mathrm{Q^{\boldsymbol{*}}QA}\:$, Figure-01, we have for the general case 
\begin{equation}
\left(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{x}^{\boldsymbol{*}}\right)=\left(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{x}\right)+\left(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}^{\boldsymbol{*}}\right)
\tag{05}
\end{equation}
so
\begin{equation}
\left\Vert\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{x}^{\boldsymbol{*}}\right\Vert^{2}=\left\Vert\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{x}\right\Vert^{2}+\left\Vert\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}^{\boldsymbol{*}}\right\Vert^{2}+2\left(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{x}\right)\boldsymbol{\cdot}\left(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}^{\boldsymbol{*}}\right)
\tag{06}
\end{equation}

Now, according to the meaning of the retarded position and time, if the charge emitted a light signal, speed $\:c$, from the retarded position $\: \mathbf{x}^{\boldsymbol{*}}$ (point $\:\mathrm{Q^{\boldsymbol{*}}}$) at the retarded time $\: t^{\boldsymbol{*}}\:$  towards field point $\:\mathrm A\:$ then this signal and the charge $\:q\:$ arrive simultaneously at field point $\:\mathrm A\:$ and position $\: \mathbf{x}$ (point $\:\mathrm Q$) respectively  at the present time moment $\:\mathrm t$. The common time duration of these travels is
\begin{equation}
\Delta t = t-t^{\boldsymbol{*}}
\tag{07}
\end{equation}
That is, during the time interval $\:\Delta t\:$ the signal travels rectilinearly the distance $\:\left\Vert\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{x}^{\boldsymbol{*}}\right\Vert\:$ with constant speed $\:c$, so :
\begin{equation}
\left\Vert\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{x}^{\boldsymbol{*}}\right\Vert= c\,\Delta t
\tag{08}
\end{equation}
while, on the other hand, the charge $\:q\:$ travels along its generally curvilinear trajectory from the position $\:\mathbf{x}^{\boldsymbol{*}}\:$ in the past to its position $\:\mathbf{x}\:$ in present time.

[image]

Let see what is happening in the special case of rectilinear motion of the charge. Without loss of generality we suppose that the charge is moving along the positive $\:x-$axis, unit vector $\:\mathbf{i}$, with constant velocity
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\left(t\right)=\boldsymbol{\upsilon}=\upsilon \mathbf{i}\,,\, \quad \upsilon \in \left(0,\boldsymbol{+}c\right) 
\tag{09}
\end{equation}
and at time $\:t=0\:$ is on the origin of the coordinate system $\:\mathrm O$, Figure-02, so :
\begin{align}
 \mathbf{x}\left(t\right) & = \left(\upsilon\,t\,\right)\,\mathbf{i}\,,\quad \mathbf{x}^{\boldsymbol{*}}= \mathbf{x}\left(t^{\boldsymbol{*}}\right) =\left(\upsilon\,t^{\boldsymbol{*}}\right)\,\mathbf{i}
 \tag{10a}\\
\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}^{\boldsymbol{*}} & =\upsilon\,\left(t-t^{\boldsymbol{*}}\right)\,\mathbf{i}=\left(\upsilon\,\Delta t\right) \,\mathbf{i}
\tag{10b}
\end{align}
and
\begin{equation}
\left\Vert\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}^{\boldsymbol{*}}\right\Vert= \upsilon \,\Delta t
\tag{11}
\end{equation}
From (06)
\begin{equation}
\underbrace{\left\Vert\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{x}^{\boldsymbol{*}}\right\Vert^{2}}_{c^{2}\left(\Delta t\right)^{2}}=\underbrace{\left\Vert\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{x}\right\Vert^{2}}_{\left(x\boldsymbol{-}\upsilon\,t\,\right)^{2}\boldsymbol{+}y^{2}\boldsymbol{+}z^{2}}+\underbrace{\left\Vert\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}^{\boldsymbol{*}}\right\Vert^{2}}_{\upsilon^{2}\left(\Delta t\right)^{2}}+\underbrace{2\left(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{x}\right)\boldsymbol{\cdot}\left(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}^{\boldsymbol{*}}\right)}_{2\,\left(x\boldsymbol{-}\upsilon\,t\,\right)\,\upsilon\,\Delta t}
\tag{12}
\end{equation}
that is
\begin{equation}
\left[c^{2}-\upsilon^{2}\right]\left(\Delta t\right)^{2}-\left[2\,\upsilon\left(x\boldsymbol{-}\upsilon\,t\,\right)\,\right]\left(\Delta t\right)-\left[\left(x\boldsymbol{-}\upsilon\,t\,\right)^{2}\boldsymbol{+}y^{2}\boldsymbol{+}z^{2}\right]=0
\tag{13}
\end{equation}
with acceptable the non-negative root<sup>(1)</sup> with respect to $\:\Delta t\:$
\begin{equation}
\Delta t =\dfrac{\upsilon\left(x\boldsymbol{-}\upsilon\,t\,\right)+\sqrt{\upsilon^{2}\left(x\boldsymbol{-}\upsilon\,t\,\right)^{2}+\left[c^{2}-\upsilon^{2}\right]\left[\left(x\boldsymbol{-}\upsilon\,t\,\right)^{2}\boldsymbol{+}y^{2}\boldsymbol{+}z^{2}\right]}}{c^{2}-\upsilon^{2}}
\tag{14}
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
\Delta t =\dfrac{\upsilon\left(x\boldsymbol{-}\upsilon\,t\,\right)+\sqrt{c^{2}\left(x\boldsymbol{-}\upsilon\,t\,\right)^{2}+\left(c^{2}-\upsilon^{2}\right)\left(y^{2}\boldsymbol{+}z^{2}\right)}}{c^{2}-\upsilon^{2}}
\tag{15}
\end{equation}
From (08)
\begin{equation}
\left\Vert\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{x}^{\boldsymbol{*}}\right\Vert=c\Delta t =\sqrt{\gamma^{2}\!-\!1}\,\gamma\left(x\boldsymbol{\!-\!}\upsilon\,t\,\right)+\gamma\sqrt{\bigl[\gamma\left(x-\upsilon t\right)\bigr]^2+y^{2}\boldsymbol{+}z^{2}} \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{1}}{\dfrac{1}{1}}}
\tag{16}
\end{equation}
For the retarded time we have
\begin{equation}
t^{\boldsymbol{*}}=t-\Delta t =\dfrac{\left(c^{2}t-\upsilon\,x\right)-\sqrt{c^{2}\left(x\boldsymbol{-}\upsilon\,t\,\right)^{2}+\left(c^{2}-\upsilon^{2}\right)\left(y^{2}\boldsymbol{+}z^{2}\right)}}{c^{2}-\upsilon^{2}}
\tag{17}
\end{equation}
so<sup>(2)</sup>
\begin{equation}
t^{\boldsymbol{*}}=t-\Delta t =\gamma^{2}\left(t-\dfrac{\upsilon}{c^{2}}\,x\right)-\dfrac{\gamma\sqrt{\bigl[\gamma\left(x-\upsilon t\right)\bigr]^2+y^{2}\boldsymbol{+}z^{2}}}{c}
\tag{18}
\end{equation}
For the retarded position 
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{x}^{\boldsymbol{*}}=\left(\upsilon\,t^{\boldsymbol{*}}\right) \,\mathbf{i}=\Biggl[\gamma^{2}\left(\upsilon\, t-\dfrac{\upsilon^{2}}{c^{2}}\,x\right)-\dfrac{\gamma\,\upsilon\,\sqrt{\bigl[\gamma\left(x-\upsilon t\right)\bigr]^2+y^{2}\boldsymbol{+}z^{2}}}{c}\Biggr]\,\mathbf{i}
\tag{19}
\end{equation}
and from this for the $x-$component of $ \left(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{x}^{\boldsymbol{*}}\right)$
\begin{align}
 \left(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{x}^{\boldsymbol{*}}\right)_{x} & =x-\Biggl[\gamma^{2}\left(\upsilon\, t-\dfrac{\upsilon^{2}}{c^{2}}\,x\right)-\dfrac{\gamma\,\upsilon\,\sqrt{\bigl[\gamma\left(x-\upsilon t\right)\bigr]^2+y^{2}\boldsymbol{+}z^{2}}}{c}\Biggr]
\nonumber\\
& = \underbrace{\left(1+\dfrac{\gamma^{2}\upsilon^{2}}{c^{2}}\right)}_{\gamma^{2}}x-\gamma^{2}\upsilon\, t+\dfrac{\gamma\,\upsilon\,\sqrt{\bigl[\gamma\left(x-\upsilon t\right)\bigr]^2+y^{2}\boldsymbol{+}z^{2}}}{c}
\nonumber\\
& =\gamma^{2}\left(x-\upsilon t\right)+\dfrac{\gamma\,\upsilon\,\sqrt{\bigl[\gamma\left(x-\upsilon t\right)\bigr]^2+y^{2}\boldsymbol{+}z^{2}}}{c} 
\tag{20}
\end{align}
that is
\begin{equation}
\left(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{x}^{\boldsymbol{*}}\right)_{x}=\gamma^{2}\left(x-\upsilon t\right)+\dfrac{\gamma\,\upsilon\,\sqrt{\bigl[\gamma\left(x-\upsilon t\right)\bigr]^2+y^{2}\boldsymbol{+}z^{2}}}{c}
\tag{21}
\end{equation}
Next
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\:\boldsymbol{\upsilon}^{\boldsymbol{*}}}{c}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\left(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{x}^{\boldsymbol{*}}\right) & = \dfrac{\:\upsilon\:}{c}\cdot\left(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{x}^{\boldsymbol{*}}\right)_{x}
\nonumber\\
& = \gamma^{2}\dfrac{\:\upsilon\:}{c}\left(x-\upsilon t\right)+\gamma\dfrac{\upsilon^{2}}{c^{2}}\sqrt{\bigl[\gamma\left(x-\upsilon t\right)\bigr]^2+y^{2}\boldsymbol{+}z^{2}}
\nonumber\\
& = \sqrt{\gamma^{2}\!-\!1}\,\gamma\left(x\boldsymbol{\!-\!}\upsilon\,t\,\right)+\left(\gamma-\dfrac{\:1\:}{\gamma}\right)\sqrt{\bigl[\gamma\left(x-\upsilon t\right)\bigr]^2+y^{2}\boldsymbol{+}z^{2}} \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{1}}{\dfrac{1}{1}}}
\tag{22}
\end{align}
so
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\:\boldsymbol{\upsilon}^{\boldsymbol{*}}}{c}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\left(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{x}^{\boldsymbol{*}}\right)=\sqrt{\gamma^{2}\!-\!1}\,\gamma\left(x\boldsymbol{\!-\!}\upsilon\,t\,\right)+\left(\gamma-\dfrac{\:1\:}{\gamma}\right)\sqrt{\bigl[\gamma\left(x-\upsilon t\right)\bigr]^2+y^{2}\boldsymbol{+}z^{2}} \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{1}}{\dfrac{1}{1}}} 
\tag{23}
\end{equation}
Subtracting (23) from (16) side by side 
\begin{equation}
\left\Vert\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{x}^{\boldsymbol{*}}\right\Vert-\dfrac{\:\boldsymbol{\upsilon}^{\boldsymbol{*}}}{c}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\left(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{x}^{\boldsymbol{*}}\right)=\dfrac{\sqrt{\bigl[\gamma\left(x-\upsilon t\right)\bigr]^2+y^{2}\boldsymbol{+}z^{2}}}{\gamma} \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{1}}{\dfrac{1}{1}}} 
\tag{24}
\end{equation}
Inserting this expression in the denominator of (03) we prove the Lorentz equation (04).

---

<sup>(1)
The roots of (13) with respect to $\:\left(\Delta t\right)\:$ are
\begin{equation}
\left(\Delta t\right)_{\boldsymbol{\pm}}=\dfrac{\upsilon\left(x\boldsymbol{-}\upsilon\,t\,\right)\boldsymbol{\pm}\sqrt{\upsilon^{2}\left(x\boldsymbol{-}\upsilon\,t\,\right)^{2}+\left[c^{2}-\upsilon^{2}\right]\left[\left(x\boldsymbol{-}\upsilon\,t\,\right)^{2}\boldsymbol{+}y^{2}\boldsymbol{+}z^{2}\right]}}{c^{2}-\upsilon^{2}}
\tag{13a}
\end{equation}
Defining for convenience the real variable $\:f=\upsilon\left(x\boldsymbol{-}\upsilon\,t\,\right)\:$ we have
\begin{align}
 \left(\Delta t\right)_{\boldsymbol{+}} & \ge \dfrac{f\boldsymbol{+}\vert f\vert}{c^{2}-\upsilon^{2}} \ge 0
\tag{13b}\\
 \left(\Delta t\right)_{\boldsymbol{-}} & \le \dfrac{f\boldsymbol{-}\vert f\vert}{c^{2}-\upsilon^{2}} \le 0
\tag{13c}
\end{align}
that is a non-negative and a non-positive root. Note that from (13)
\begin{equation}
\left(\Delta t\right)_{\boldsymbol{+}}\cdot \left(\Delta t\right)_{\boldsymbol{-}} =-\dfrac{\left(x\boldsymbol{-}\upsilon\,t\,\right)^{2}\boldsymbol{+}y^{2}\boldsymbol{+}z^{2}}{c^{2}-\upsilon^{2}}\le 0
\tag{13a}
\end{equation}
Acceptable is the non-negative one, equation (14).</sup>

---

<sup>(2)
There exists an interpretation of equation (18) via the Lorentz transformation. This equation is expressed as follows
\begin{equation}
t^{\boldsymbol{*}}=\gamma\Biggl[\gamma\left(t-\dfrac{\upsilon}{c^{2}}\,x\right)-\dfrac{\sqrt{\bigl[\gamma\left(x-\upsilon t\right)\bigr]^2+y^{2}\boldsymbol{+}z^{2}}}{c}\Biggr]
\tag{25}
\end{equation}
We agreed previously, see after (09), that $\:t=t_{0}=0\:$ when the charge $\:q\:$ is on the origin $\:\mathrm O\:$ of the frame $\:\mathrm Oxyz$. Now, we agree also to set $\:\tau=\tau_{0}=0\:$ when $\:q\:$ on the origin $\:\mathrm O$, where $\:\tau\:$ the time in the rest frame of the charge $\:q\:$, that is its proper time.</sup>

<sup>Let the two events
\begin{align}
 E_{1} & = q\:\:\text{on the origin}\:\: \mathrm O
\tag{26.1}\\
 E_{2} & = \text{the light signal emitted from retarded position arrives at field point  }\:\mathrm A
\tag{26.2}
\end{align}
The space-time intervals that separate these two events are : first in $\:\mathrm Oxyz$
\begin{align}
 \overset{\boldsymbol{-}}{\Delta} x & = x_{2}-x_{1}=x-0=x\,,\quad  x=\text{coordinate of field point}\:\: \mathrm A 
\tag{27.1}\\
 \overset{\boldsymbol{-}}{\Delta} t & = t_{2}-t_{1}=t-0=t\,,\quad  t=\text{present time}
\tag{27.2}
\end{align}
and second in the rest frame of $\:q\:$
\begin{align}
 \overset{\boldsymbol{-}}{\Delta} x^{(q)} & = x^{(q)}_{2}-x^{(q)}_{1}=x^{(q)}-0=x^{(q)}\,,\quad  x^{(q)}=\text{coordinate of field point}\:\: \mathrm A 
\tag{28.1}\\
 \overset{\boldsymbol{-}}{\Delta} \tau & = \tau_{2}-\tau_{1}=\tau-0=\tau\,,\quad  \tau=\text{present proper time}
\tag{28.2}
\end{align}
where $\:x^{(q)},y^{(q)},z^{(q)}\:$ the coordinates in the rest frame of the charge $\:q$.</sup>

<sup>The Lorentz transformation equations are
\begin{align}
\overset{\boldsymbol{-}}{\Delta} x^{(q)} & = \gamma\left(\overset{\boldsymbol{-}}{\Delta} x-\upsilon\,\overset{\boldsymbol{-}}{\Delta} t\right)
\tag{29.1}\\
\overset{\boldsymbol{-}}{\Delta} y^{(q)} & = \hphantom{\left(\!a\right)} \overset{\boldsymbol{-}}{\Delta} y
\tag{29.2}\\
\overset{\boldsymbol{-}}{\Delta} z^{(q)} & = \hphantom{\left(\!a\right)}\overset{\boldsymbol{-}}{\Delta} z
\tag{29.3}\\
\overset{\boldsymbol{-}}{\Delta} \tau & = \gamma\left(\overset{\boldsymbol{-}}{\Delta} t-\dfrac{\upsilon}{c^{2}}\,\overset{\boldsymbol{-}}{\Delta} x\right) 
\tag{29.4}
\end{align}
and inserting the space-time intervals (27),(28)
\begin{align}
x^{(q)} & = \gamma\left( x-\upsilon\,t\right)
\tag{30.1}\\
y^{(q)} & = \hphantom{\left(\!a\right)} y
\tag{30.2}\\
z^{(q)} & = \hphantom{\left(\!a\right)} z
\tag{30.3}\\
\tau & = \gamma\left(t-\dfrac{\upsilon}{c^{2}}\, x\right) 
\tag{30.4}
\end{align}
We recognize at once that the first term in the bracket of the rhs of (25) is the present proper time $\:\tau\:$, so
\begin{equation}
t^{\boldsymbol{*}}=\gamma\Biggl[\tau-\dfrac{\sqrt{\bigl[\gamma\left(x-\upsilon t\right)\bigr]^2+y^{2}\boldsymbol{+}z^{2}}}{c}\Biggr]
\tag{31}
\end{equation}
We proceed now to the interpretation of the second term in the brackets, that with the square root.</sup>

<sup>In frame $\:\mathrm Oxyz\:$ the signal emitted from the retarded position $\:\mathbf{x}^{\boldsymbol{*}}\:$ (point $\:\mathrm Q^{\boldsymbol{*}}$) towards the field point $\:\mathrm A\:$ travels from the start to the end of the vector $\:\left(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{x}^{\boldsymbol{*}}\right)\:$ component-wise
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{x}^{\boldsymbol{*}}=
\begin{bmatrix}
x-\upsilon\, t^{\boldsymbol{*}} \vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
y\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
z\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{32}
\end{equation}
spending time, see (14)
\begin{align}
\Delta t
&=\dfrac{\left\Vert\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{x}^{\boldsymbol{*}}\right\Vert}{c}= \dfrac{\sqrt{\left(x\boldsymbol{-}\upsilon\,t^{\boldsymbol{*}}\,\right)^{2}\boldsymbol{+}y^{2}\boldsymbol{+}z^{2}}}{c}
\tag{33}\\
&=\dfrac{\upsilon\left(x\boldsymbol{-}\upsilon\,t\,\right)+\sqrt{\upsilon^{2}\left(x\boldsymbol{-}\upsilon\,t\,\right)^{2}+\left[c^{2}-\upsilon^{2}\right]\left[\left(x\boldsymbol{-}\upsilon\,t\,\right)^{2}\boldsymbol{+}y^{2}\boldsymbol{+}z^{2}\right]}}{c^{2}-\upsilon^{2}}
\nonumber
\end{align}
But in the rest frame of the charge the signal seems to travel from its present position $\:\mathbf{x}\:$ (point $\:\mathrm Q$) towards the field point $\:\mathrm A\:$, that is  from the start to the end of the vector $\:\left(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{x}\right)\:$ **component-wise in the frame $\:\mathrm Oxyz$**
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{x}=
\begin{bmatrix}
x-\upsilon\, t \vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
y\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
z\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{34}
\end{equation}
and according to the above Lorentz transformation **component-wise in the rest frame of the charge**
\begin{equation}
\left(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{x}\right)^{(q)}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\gamma\left(x-\upsilon\, t\right) \vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
y\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
z\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{35}
\end{equation}
spending proper time
\begin{equation}
\Delta \tau
=\dfrac{\left\Vert \left(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{x}\right)^{(q)}  \right\Vert}{c}= \dfrac{\sqrt{\bigl[\gamma\left(x-\upsilon t\right)\bigr]^2+y^{2}\boldsymbol{+}z^{2}}}{c}=\tau-\tau^{\boldsymbol{*}}
\tag{36}
\end{equation}
and (31) yields
\begin{equation}
t^{\boldsymbol{*}}=\gamma\tau^{\boldsymbol{*}}
\tag{37}
\end{equation}
Note : Because of the very much misunderstanding meaning of time dilation, I don't dare to refer to (37) as  a time dilation one, since it could be expressed as
\begin{equation}
t^{\boldsymbol{*}}\boldsymbol{-}\underbrace{t_{0}}_{=0}=\gamma\left(\tau^{\boldsymbol{*}}\boldsymbol{-}\underbrace{\tau_{0}}_{=0}\right)
\tag{38}
\end{equation}</sup>

Comment: +1, for the answer. How do you create such marvellous images?

Comment: @exp ikx  :  It's Geogebra. One of its advantages is that you can insert symbols and equations in LaTeX.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was GeoGebra, but didn't know we can use LaTeX. Btw, I have used one of your images in a [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/474350/how-can-direction-of-electric-field-due-to-a-moving-charge-be-from-the-present-p) of mine. Due credit is given, hope you don't mind.

Comment: @exp ikx : Of course I don't mind. This stuff is  property of PSE and its users.