# Why do the Feynman-Heaviside formulae for $\vec E, \vec B$ fields differ from the Lienard-Wiechert fields?

Tags: electromagnetism

Why do the expressions for Feynman-Heaviside fields look completely different from the Lienard-Wiechart fields though both of which are fields due to a point charge moving along a specified trajectory? I don't understand this. For a reference, refer to eq. (23.31), (23.32), (23.49) and (23.50) of Andrew Zangwill's Modern Electrodynamics.

I give them below for ready reference:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/168783), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/479421) instead.

Comment: In my opinion to prove the Feynman's equations you must derive  first the Lienard-Wiechert equations for the potentials. See my .pdf file "A Feynman Lectures EM Equation" here [Deriving Heaviside-Feynman formula for the electric field of an arbitrarily moving charge from Lienard-Wiechert potential](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/139238/deriving-heaviside-feynman-formula-for-the-electric-field-of-an-arbitrarily-movi/373441#373441). It's an effort to prove the Feynman's equations...

Comment: ...The Lienard-Wiechert equations for the potential are derived in an intermediate step, see equations (4-2.24) and (4-2.25) in the file. It's a long length tedious elaboration and I don't expect for anybody to watch it till the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly: they are equivalent. Feynman claims in the Feynman Lectures that you can easily check this by doing the differentiation in his formula and comparing with the fields derived from the L-W potentials. It's taken me a lifetime of trying and giving up because it's so difficult before I worked out how to do it reasonably efficiently. I ought probably to write this up and publish it!

So secondly, I think the real reason is that Feynman was very proud of his formula, which does indeed give real insight into what's going on and how it relates to the static charge case, but wanted to cover his tracks so everybody would think 'Wow how ever did he find that?' He references the formula very early in Chapter 1 of Volume 1, and again in its more natural position in the elctrodynamics volume, II, and then purports to derive it without actually doing so. There has to be an explanation, and I think this is the most natural one.

Comment: Having now looked at one of the related questions I see that quite a number of people have followed the same trajectory of struggling to find a straightforward way of deriving the Feynman version! I think this is *exactly* what Feynman wanted!!